# Непонятки в коде реализации визуализации

Tags: java

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь приделать комбинацию клавиш на пункт меню "Открыть файл" в созданном мною блокноте.

Итак. Обычным кликом мыши я задействую такой механизм:

```
//JMenuItem openF - объект пункта верхнего меню "Открыть файл" моего блокнота 
    openF.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                    int value = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if(value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                            StringBuilder mainLine = new StringBuilder();
                            String inputText;

                            while((inputText = br.readLine())!=null){
                                mainLine.append(inputText);
                            }

                            outputText = mainLine.toString();

                            System.out.println(outputText);
                            jTextArea.setText(outputText);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Notepad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Notepad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Теперь я хочу сделать туже операцию, но при нажимании клавиш CTRL+O.
Приделываю KeyListener к JTextArea jTextArea

```
jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e ){

                if(e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O){

                    //что здесь должно быть?? конечно же не по новой создавать 
                    //JFileChooser. как воспользоваться уже существующим? Его нужно                  //было поместить в какой то метод, прежде чем использовать его выше?

                }
            }
        });
```

Очень признателен за помощь

Comment: прошу максимум критики

Comment: Сделать в этом классе объект Runnable, куда в метод run засунуть нужный код и в обоих случаях запускать этот Runnable.

Comment: а нужна ли здесь многопоточность?

Comment: Раны можно запускать в своем потоке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выносите из listener этот код

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                    int value = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if(value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

И поместит его в метод File getFile()

Ну и вызываейте его.